# Foreach loop with import-csv

Tags: powershell

Having some issue using basic import-csv in a loop function.

1. I have basic csv file with hostname, node headers
2. I am assigning the file using import-csv
3. Then I am then simply starting `foreach` loop when I am trying to test-path using the hostname within unc path `\\$r.hostname\c$\users\something\desktop`
4. Expected result is true
5. But the actual result is false

when I am trying the actual hostname in the test-path instead of the csv param its working just fine.

```
$records = Import-Csv C:\Users\someuser\Desktop\partition-mapping.csv

foreach ($r in $records)
{

    Test-Path -LiteralPath \\$r.hostname\c$\users   <<====not working 

    Test-Path -LiteralPath \\hostname01.lab.local\C$\Users\ <<====== workign fine



}
```

as always you guys are awesome !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just test :

```
 Test-Path -LiteralPath "\\$($r.hostname)\c$\users"   <<====now working ;o)
```

The trouble comes from the fact that `$r` is directly interpreted as a var, so the final string is `"\\$r collection as a string.hostname\c$\users"`